# Typescript nested object optional properties error with 'satisfies'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define types for my project to have a generic approach and at the same time be able to narrow on specific property of my objects in the workflow.

the `satisfies` operator seemed to be exactly what I needed because I could use generic type on my object and keep a strong typesafety while avoiding too much boilerplate code to narrow types.

But I'm having a hard time using optionnal properties because they don't appear as an option in the autocomplete and I get an IDE error.

```js
const formatterFunctions = {
    foo: () => (true),
    bar: undefined,
} as const
type FormatterFunctionsKeys = keyof typeof formatterFunctions

type MyObj = {
    type: 'normal' | 'function',
    message: string,
    formatter?: typeof formatterFunctions[FormatterFunctionsKeys]
};

const objArray = {
    foo: { type: 'function', message: 'someMessage', formatter: formatterFunctions.foo},
    bar: {type: 'normal', message: 'barMessage'}
 } satisfies {[K in FormatterFunctionsKeys]: MyObj}

 for (const [key, entry] of Object.entries(objArray)) {
    entry.formatter // <= error here 'formatter' doesn't appear in the autocomplete, and typing it manually creates an error. The only property are 'type' and 'message'.
 }
```

The ts error message:

```
 Property 'formatter' does not exist on type '{ type: "function"; message: string; formatter: () => boolean; } | { type: "normal"; message: string; }'.
```

Can you help me find what's wrong with the way I'm defining my types?
My goal is to have the autocomplete and correct typing while still using `satisfies`.

Precision: the code is an example of my more complex case. But a MyObj object can be type: 'normal' and have a formatter functions.

Comment: You can't fine-tune `satisfies`'s behavior.  You *could* reassign `objArray` to a variable of the desired type, though, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NlXyON).  Then `objArray` stays narrow (which I suppose you need for some reason) and you can still iterate.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I hadn't though of that and it will definetely come in handy in the futur so yeah that's actually a great answer, I will accept it. I ended up going another way, So I'll write it up too. Thank alot @jcalz !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fine-tune how [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) works, so there's no direct way to say "please also keep track of omitted [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties)".  Let's say we name the relevant type `ObjArray`:

```
type ObjArray = { [K in FormatterFunctionsKeys]: MyObj };
```

Then writing

```
const objArray = {
  foo: { type: 'function', message: 'someMessage', formatter: formatterFunctions.foo },
  bar: { type: 'normal', message: 'barMessage' }
} satisfies ObjArray;
```

only checks/guarantees that the type of `objArray` will be *assignable to* `ObjArray`, not that it can be directly used as one.  In a perfectly [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) type system, that would be equivalent, but there are some holes in the type system, and the way optional properties are treated is one such hole (see [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#42479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42479#issuecomment-767226743) for the basic issue).

But since you know that `objArray` is assignable to `ObjArray`, if you run into trouble, one approach you can take is to *assign* it to someplace expecting an `ObjArray` and then use that.

You could do this by actually assigning to another variable:

```
const myObjArray: ObjArray = objArray; // okay
for (const [key, entry] of Object.entries(myObjArray)) {
  entry.formatter // okay
}
```

Or by making a function and passing `objArray` to that function:

```
function doStuff(objArray: ObjArray) {
  for (const [key, entry] of Object.entries(myObjArray)) {
    entry.formatter // okay
  }
}
doStuff(objArray); // okay
```

Or even just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) for expedience.

```
for (const [key, entry] of Object.entries(objArray as ObjArray)) {
  entry.formatter // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiATgWwIZSgU0QMQK5jBQCW4EMAvDAN4BQM8IIAXDABQCUlAfO1InkwcANPRgAjVIlYEAJpjjEwmWaIC+MVOVCQotKAE8ADphg4kaDNnyESZANKYD5KgGsnIODEMnPjFOhYuAREpJC0+samALIGAPLiAFaUNGI+mKwA5GAWqAA2mTAAPjCZcCF2YJmiDMiYEBCoAOYZMNCISk01-pZBAPys6X4IAVbBtmEQANrmo0E2oQ5OEAC6tGoA3BHpMAmJAIKIiKgGKdQwU-YwSma5YwuVEI7OK6yxezCbETrQMCBJh2OpyodAYCBYNG8USy5Qm4GqMDqDWarUyEBAdWi9UaLQRI162FY+MC1gqkwAdODPt1JNJIeksjkAgVhIjsSisrSscjcZ91m10MQIIp6rsAUcTt8yLBkPFxUDWHtAScUv8DhKDFsRuwfrApu4DKzMGB+AYVn8vHtMERycb+MR6mxZUqNRwuKCYHbEAZKXcgjAAPQBv6uSVqCKwxZgGCyEAAZSgeDgcDYauVBkV8pO7rE2rYuouBqNJu95r8VptXodECdcvVQLdqQYDC9PuJY0DwZAoYMYnD4djCaTKbTro2nZDktoeYL+qcxdNZctSWtUFtJerqazpy0Yvr2ZzLZLbb92An3bDtCAA)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is due to the TypeScript type inference and how you've defined the objArray object. The objArray object is not being inferred with the correct types, which is why you're not getting autocomplete suggestions for the formatter property. To fix this, you can explicitly define the type of objArray to ensure TypeScript correctly infers the types. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
const formatterFunctions = {
    foo: () => true,
    bar: undefined,
} as const;

type FormatterFunctionsKeys = keyof typeof formatterFunctions;

type MyObj = {
    type: 'normal' | 'function';
    message: string;
    formatter?: typeof formatterFunctions[FormatterFunctionsKeys];
};

const objArray: Record<FormatterFunctionsKeys, MyObj> = {
    foo: { type: 'function', message: 'someMessage', formatter: formatterFunctions.foo },
    bar: { type: 'normal', message: 'barMessage' },
};

for (const [key, entry] of Object.entries(objArray)) {
    entry.formatter; // Now autocomplete should work, and there should be no typing errors.
}
```

In this code, I've explicitly defined objArray as a Record with keys from FormatterFunctionsKeys and values of type MyObj. This ensures that TypeScript correctly infers the types for objArray, and you should get autocomplete suggestions for the formatter property as expected.

Comment: That's what I tried initialy, but by switching to a definition instead of using `satisfies` we lose the narrowing. In the example, it's not that big a deal, but in my real case scenario it is. Is it possible to have the autocomplete and correct typing while still using `satisfies`?

Comment: But thank you for the answer :)